# nodejs without template engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine

I just started learning backend development and I decided to start with node js. I figured out express js and routing a bit. This question came to my mind. Is there a way to send data directly to ready html files without using any Template Engine technology? Do we have to use Template Engine technology?

Comment: You can edit files like strings, that's what template engines do

Answer (score 2):

In Express.js, you can definitely send data directly to HTML files without using a template engine. While template engines like EJS, Handlebars, or Pug are commonly used to dynamically render HTML templates with data, you can also send raw HTML files with placeholders and replace those placeholders with data on the server side.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   const html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
  res.send(html);
});
```

You can use the express.static middleware to serve static files, including HTML files. Here's how you can do it:

Create a folder called "public" in your project directory and place your HTML files inside it. For example, let's assume you have an HTML file called "index.html" inside the "public" folder.

Set up Express to serve static files from the "public" folder:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Is there a way to send json data from nodejs to frontend javascript? Or something? Or can we only send data in these ways?

Comment: Yes you can send data with json using res.json() method
Efficient way : res.json(jsondata)
Other ways: res.send(jsondata) ,res.end(jsondata)

Comment: I want to send data with an html page already created,but only res.send() is working and res.sendfile() is not working. Is there a way to convert the data from mysql to json data and send it with a current html file?